# Mapreduce with multiple mappers and reducers

Tags: hadoop2

I am trying to implement multiple mappers and reducers code. Here is my main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create a new configuration
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    Path out = new Path(args[1]);
    try {
        //This is the first job to get the number of providers per state
        Job numberOfProvidersPerStateJob = Job.getInstance(configuration, "Total number of Providers per state");
        //Set the Jar file class, mapper and reducer class
        numberOfProvidersPerStateJob.setJarByClass(ProviderCount.class);
        numberOfProvidersPerStateJob.setMapperClass(MapForProviderCount.class);
        numberOfProvidersPerStateJob.setReducerClass(ReduceForProviderCount.class);

        numberOfProvidersPerStateJob.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        numberOfProvidersPerStateJob.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        //Provide the input and output argument this will be needed when running the jar file in hadoop
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(numberOfProvidersPerStateJob, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(numberOfProvidersPerStateJob, new Path(out,"out1"));
        if (!numberOfProvidersPerStateJob.waitForCompletion(true)) {
              System.exit(1);
            }
        //Job 2 for getting the state with maximum provider
        Job maxJobProviderState = Job.getInstance(configuration, "State With Max Job providers");
        //Set the Jar file class, mapper and reducer class
        maxJobProviderState.setJarByClass(ProviderCount.class);
        maxJobProviderState.setMapperClass(MapForMaxProvider.class);
        maxJobProviderState.setReducerClass(ReducerForMaxProvider.class);

        maxJobProviderState.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        maxJobProviderState.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        //Provide the input and output argument this will be needed when running the jar file in hadoop
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(maxJobProviderState, new Path(out,"out1"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(maxJobProviderState, new Path(out,"out2"));
        //Exit when results are ready
        System.exit(maxJobProviderState.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);


    }
```

The problem is whenever I am running it. It gives me final output from 2nd mapper class and not the reducer class. It is something like my 2nd reducer class is getting ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement ChainMappers using ( org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain.ChainMapper )and ChainReducers using (  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain.ChainReducer ) , It will resolve your issue.

Comment: I figured it out. My reducer method signature was not correct so it was not overriding the reducer method and hence my reducer method in second reducer class was getting ignored. @Override should be used on top of method signature to avoid such issues